# Printing "*" with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I would need some help to solve one exercise. In this method I have to print the number of asterisks ("*") that are equal of 2 of power of x.

For example, if I have 2 of power of 2 it should print 4 asterisks ("****");

I have a method that returns me the right number, but I have problems using that number for printing those asterisks.

Here is my code:

```
public static int writeStars(int number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int number2 = 2 * writeStars(number - 1);
        System.out.println(" number " + number2);
        return number2;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but I have problems using that number for printing those asterisks." -- What problems might those be? You haven't included any of your asterisk-printing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea for solving the problem, without giving away the solution in code.

Your thoughts are on the right track, realizing that 2<sup>x</sup> = 2 * 2<sup>x-1</sup>.  To print 2<sup>x</sup> `*` characters, you can print 2<sup>x-1</sup> *twice*.  In your recursive method, have your base case print one `*` character, and have your recursive case make the recursive call *twice*, passing the appropriately adjusted value.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved (:

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create a string of 2^(i-1) stars at the i-th iteration. So, for 4 iterations (x=4), you will have 8,4,2,1 stars for each iteration. You can return the string of stars for each iteration and concatenate them to get the final string.

The terminating condition will be when the input size is 0. This code might help:

```
public static String writeStars(int y) {
    //y is 2^x
    if( y == 0)
      return "";
    int num_stars = y - y/2;
    StringBuffer stars_Buffer = new StringBuffer(num_stars);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_stars; i++){
         stars_Buffer.append("");
    }
   return stars_Buffer.toString() + writeStars(y/2);
}
```

Call writeStars with input 2^x:

```
writeStars(Math.pow(2, x));
```

Comment: Did you try compiling this? You're returning a `String` here `return ""`when the method return type is `int`. Also, no semicolon.

Comment: thanks @robotlos, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a return method in your client you should have

```
int num = writeStars(someNum);
```

Then to print, you just need a simple for loop

```
for(int i=0; i < num; i++)
   System.out.print("*");
```